# Merging rasters in R - errors using mosaic function

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, mosaic

I'm trying to use the `mosaic` function (package: `raster`) in R to join two geo-tiff rasters together. Both are derived from LandSat tiles. I understand that mosaic requires

> All objects must have the same origin, resolution, and coordinate
>   reference system.

Unfortunately, the two tiles have different CRS

```
+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

and

```
+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

leading to

```
Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different CRS
```

So, I converted them to the same crs by using `projectRaster` - I've tried reprojecting both rasters to both epsg:3857 and epsg:4326

However, having done this, in both cases when I run the `mosaic` function I get the error

```
Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different origin
```

How can I fix this? Is there a different crs I could use that would use the same origin for both?

Answer (score 1):

So my workaround was to create a very large raster file (just drew it out in QGIS) that covers the entirety of the desired area, then `resample` using that raster for the parameters.